# Python divide rows by specific row for each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I need to divide each row by a specific/set row for each column in my data frame. In this case, I need to divide every row by Revenue for each time period. I want to get a percentage of how much each account is of Revenue. I would also like to figure out how to make dynamic for any amount of columns.

My current Data frame:

```
data = {'202112 YTD': {'Gross Margin': 200000,
  'Other (Income) & Expense': -100000,
  'Revenue': 5000000,
  'SG&A Expense': 150000,
  'Segment EBITDA': 200000},
 '202212 YTD': {'Gross Margin': 2850000,
  'Other (Income) & Expense': -338000,
  'Revenue': 6000000,
  'SG&A Expense': 15000,
  'Segment EBITDA': 200000}}


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

Desired Output:

```
outdata = {'202112 YTD': {'Gross Margin': 0.040,
  'Other (Income) & Expense': -0.020,
  'Revenue': 1,
  'SG&A Expense': 0.030,
  'Segment EBITDA': 0.040},
 '202212 YTD': {'Gross Margin': 0.475,
  'Other (Income) & Expense': -0.056,
  'Revenue': 1,
  'SG&A Expense': 0.003,
  'Segment EBITDA': 0.033}}


outdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(outdata)
outdf
```

Help would be appreciated. Original attempt as was to structure solution like this example:

```
import copy
import pandas as pd

original_table = [
    {'name': 'Alice', 'age': 25, 'gender': 'Female'},
    {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 32, 'gender': 'Male'},
    {'name': 'Charlie', 'age': 40, 'gender': 'Male'},
    {'name': 'Daisy', 'age': 22, 'gender': 'Female'},
    {'name': 'Eve', 'age': 18, 'gender': 'Female'},
]



# Duplicate the table using copy.deepcopy()
duplicate_table = copy.deepcopy(original_table)

# Choose a specific column to divide the rows by
column_name = 'age'
divisor_value = original_table[3][column_name]

# Iterate over the rows in the duplicate table and divide each column by the divisor value
for i, row in enumerate(duplicate_table):
    if column_name in row:
        duplicate_table[i][column_name] = row[column_name] / divisor_value
    else:
        print(f"column: {column_name} not found in table")

# Convert the duplicate table to a DataFrame
duplicate_df = pd.DataFrame(duplicate_table)

# Print the duplicate DataFrame
duplicate_df

duplicate_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
outdf = df.div(df.loc['Revenue']).round(3)
```

Output:

```
                          202112 YTD  202212 YTD
Gross Margin                    0.04       0.475
Other (Income) & Expense       -0.02      -0.056
Revenue                         1.00       1.000
SG&A Expense                    0.03       0.002
Segment EBITDA                  0.04       0.033
```